# How do I display a "category products drop down in a wordpress page" in Woocommerce 2.5.2

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to display a drop down menu for products in a category.

```
<select>
  <option value="CODE HERE">Volvo</option>
</select>
```

So according to Wordpress coding..

```
<?php

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Okay so I investigated further and I am looking to do a single page template according to [https://developer.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) I am using a child theme for Storefront which is called NOVA WP.

To make this "single page template"  I copied page.php and renamed it to `page-buildit.php`

This is [Mypage](http://www.ofixcomp.com/buildit/) in which I actually editing the code. I did copy the code but it turns out blank

found this: [WooCommerce: Create a shortcode to display product categories](http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-create-a-shortcode-to-display-product-categories/)
but my undestanding is we cant do this anymore with the new wordpress version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
    'include'    => $ids,
    'posts_per_page' =>'-1'
);
$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
echo "<select>";
foreach( $product_categories as $category ){
    echo "<option value = '" . esc_attr( $category->slug ) . "'>" . esc_html( $category->name ) . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Check this out. This is the way to get product categories.!

Comment: where do I input this?

Comment: Dashboard > products > Categories

Comment: I dont get it. My main objective is: Show categories list in a Wordpress page not in a Wordpress template.

Comment: Yes you can add your categories hrere -> `Dashboard > products > Categories` if you run my code in you custom pages, you will get all the categories as `<select>` which is added in `Dashboard > products > Categories`. You get it.?

Comment: sorry, but it did not work. I have latest wordpress and latest woocommerce. I made a new category called Categories, I pasted your code in the description , then I went to the frontpage and looked at the category.

Comment: @ingalcala This code doesn't go in the description of the categories. This goes directly into the template file of your theme. Preferably a child theme if you didn't build the theme yourself. For which file to edit, refer to the template hierarchy https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: Also there is no escaping here leaving you vulnerable to attacks by malicious data. Between the brackets for the `foreach` replace the code with:
`echo "<option value = '" . esc_attr( $category->slug ) . "'>" . esc_html( $category->name ) . "</option>";`

Learn more about [writing secure code](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation)

Comment: @ingalcala Wait.! Are you pasting this in you Product Description.?

Comment: I was but I read more this few days and now I am pasting it into page-buildit.php ; my child theme single page template file.

Comment: Create a new page called test. add page-test.php in your theme and paste this code and visit the page. Your categories which you added in wp-admin will be displayed in combo-box. This is how it works.!

Comment: I just noticed this is not for the products inside the category, but instead categories itself..

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the function **wp_dropdown_categories** to make your code simpler.
To get a dropdown of categories of products you can write like this.

```
$args = array('hide_empty'=> 0,
  'taxonomy'=> 'product_cat',
  'hierarchical'=>1);

wp_dropdown_categories($args);
```

Or if you want to hold the output in a variable you can use the argument 'echo'=>0 and then echo the variable to get the same output.

```
$args = array('hide_empty'=> 0,
    'taxonomy'=> 'product_cat',
    'hierarchical'=>1,
    'echo'=>0);

$cats = wp_dropdown_categories($args);
echo $cats;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so here is how I solved it, with the help of Hemnath mouli, I already gave you the credit for the answer but I wanted to publish the products inside a category in a dropbox.

```
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'product_cat' => 'motherboard',
'post_type' => 'product',
'orderby' => 'title',
);
$products = new WP_Query( $args );
echo "<select>";
foreach ( $products as $product ) {
$products->the_post();
?>      
<option value="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?>    
<?php
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Now I will need to show the image of this product after selecting it.