# Display with a shortcode a dropdown of Woocommerce products for a specific category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, dropdown, shortcode

i want to display product by category with dropdown

and i made this code but why the value not going inside the ?

```
function rakitpc() {
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'product_cat' => 'Tshirts',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'echo' => '0'
    );
    $products = new WP_Query( $args );
    $output = '<select>';
    // foreach ( $products as $product ) {
    while ( $products->have_posts() ) {
        $products->the_post();
        $aa = the_permalink($post);
        echo $aa;
        $bb = the_title($post);
        $output .= "<option value=\"<?php the_permalink(); ?>\"> <?php the_permalink(); ?></option>";  
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    $output .='</select>';
    return $output;
    }
add_shortcode( 'gege', 'rakitpc' );
```

This is the output That I get:

[image: output]

My reference: [How do I display a "category products drop down in a wordpress page" in Woocommerce 2.5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35471966/how-do-i-display-a-category-products-drop-down-in-a-wordpress-page-in-woocomme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following that will give you a dropdown with the permalinks as `<option>` values displaying the product names *(see the screenshot at the end)*.

You will need to set your category name (or categories names) in the array inside the funtion.

```
function rakitpc() {
    // HERE below, define your Product category names
    $term_names = array('T-shirts');

    // The WP_Query
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'tax_query' => array( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', // for a Product category (or 'product_tag' for a Product tag)
            'field'    => 'name',        // can be 'name', 'slug' or 'term_id'
            'terms'    => $term_names,
        ) ),
        'echo' => '0'
    ) );

    $output = '<select>';
    // foreach ( $products as $product ) {
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

        $permalink = get_permalink($query->post->ID);
        $title = $query->post->post_title;
        $output .= '<option value="' . $permalink . '">' . $title . '</option>';

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    $output .='</select>';

    else :

    $output = '<p>No products found<p>';

    endif;

    return $output;
}

add_shortcode( 'gege', 'rakitpc' );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: I get this error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\flatsome-child\functions.php on line 121

Error reference to this line:
 $query = new WP_Query( array(

Comment: woocommerce version 3.3.5

Comment: @LuqmanulHakim Ok perfect … Updated the code … Please try it again, It will work now. *(Sorry there was a missing `;`)*

Comment: Cool it work like a charm :), much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What if you wanted to do this programmatically and not statically like getting the WordPress category name from the URL in order to display the products. How would you recommend going about that?

Comment: @ChinomsoJohnson If you have in your URL a variable like `…/?category=cars`, you can replace `'terms' => $term_names` by `'terms' => esc_attr($_GET['category'])`and `'field'    => 'name'` by `'field' => 'slug'` for example. If you are using a product category archive page, you can use `'terms' => get_queried_object_id()'` with `'field'    => 'term_id'`

Comment: @LoicTheAztec. Thank you very much. That worked perfectly.