# how to display woocommerce product category and product in dropdown?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i want to display Woocommerce category and product in dropdown like this:

[image]

when click on "category dropdown" then show products in the category selected.
may code for category is :

```
$orderby = 'name';
$order = 'asc';
$hide_empty = false ;
$cat_args = array(
'orderby'    => $orderby,
'order'      => $order,
'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
);

$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $cat_args );

if( !empty($product_categories) ){
echo '

<select>';
foreach ($product_categories as $key => $category) {
    echo '

<option>';
    echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($category).'" >';
    echo $category->name;
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</option>';
}
echo '</select>


';
 }
```

how can i add product and other field? or is there any plugin for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35471966/how-do-i-display-a-category-products-drop-down-in-a-wordpress-page-in-woocomme

Comment: @RST thanks. this is similar my first code for category. but how can i nested with product and quantity?

Comment: You will either have to collect all data and make it available through click events, or make a click event trigger an AJAX request to retrieve the needed data.

Comment: @RST how can do this??

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a  coding service. You will have to start fiddling with the code on your own and come back when you have a specific coding problem. I would suggest to start with the code in the link I provided. That code is better than what you shared. Your other option is to find a plugin.